# How to run multiple statements in command line?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

Is it possible to get run multiple commands in Python from command line in Windows?

Here's what I tried on command line in Windows.

```
python -c print(4)\nprint(5)
```

The error I received was the following:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Is what I wrote above even possible to do?

Can I run multiple statements such as the following:

```
python -c a=5\nb=3\nprint(a+b)
```

And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons, instead of newlines

```
python -c "print(4); print(5)"
# prints 4, and then 5
python -c "a=5; b=3; print(a+b)"
# prints 8
```

Comment: Newlines work fine, if you actually pass a newline, and not the literal characters ``\`` and `n`, as part of the argument.

Comment: Thanks Green Cloak Guy.  What's the rationale behind using the double quotes?  I think I came across it in some documentation, but I didn't understand why it's necessary.

Comment: The double-quotes tell your shell to treat everything inside of them *as a single token*, instead of as separate tokens - regardless of any separators or whatever. In this case, they're basically required - the only way to pass a line break is to put it inside quotes (otherwise it ends the line in the shell; `\n` doesn't really work on the shell, as you've discovered), and `;` would do the same thing if it wasn't in quotes. Single-quotes should work just as well (at least in Bash they're interchangeable; I don't know if that's the case in Powershell)

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that some parameters within functions don't seem to work in terminal either.  For example, setting a,b=1,2 in Python then trying to print as print(a,b,sep='#') doesn't work.  What's the reason for this?  Does terminal or any other shell for that matter implicitly treat parameters differently for some reason?

Comment: Each `python -c` command will execute independently of any other. If you want to do both `a,b=1,2` and `print(a,b,sep='#')`, you have to put them in the same command. On my machine, `python3 -c "a,b=1,2;print(a,b,sep='#')"` produces the expected output of `1#2`